# Visual Studio 2010 complains about database versions

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, version, sqlexception

Good day once more.

Okay so what I want to do is to keep my database in the App_Data folder for ease of use, now I thought this would be easy: Copy the database into the folder and change the connection string. But when I try that I get the horrible version error:

> The database
>   'C:\USERS\GUÐMUNDUR\DESKTOP\TEST\TEST\APP_DATA\IRIS2.MDF'
>   cannot be opened because it is version
>   661. This server supports version 655 and earlier. A downgrade path is not
>   supported. Could not open new database
>   'C:\USERS\GUÐMUNDUR\DESKTOP\TEST\TEST\APP_DATA\IRIS2.MDF'.
>   CREATE DATABASE is aborted. An attempt
>   to attach an auto-named database for
>   file
>   C:\Users\Guðmundur\Desktop\Test\Test\App_Data\IRIS2.mdf
>   failed. A database with the same name
>   exists, or specified file cannot be
>   opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Now I was wondering if anyone can suggest a solution to this, I can recreate the database via the SQL script so there is no problem with that and there is no important (yet) information there.

Any ideas?

Here is the connection string:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|IRIS2.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

***The solution I used***

I went into the SQL Server Management Studio and attached the database there while keeping it in the App_Data folder. Than I went into Visual Studio, created a new Data Connection and after it was created I clicked on it and went into Properties tab for it and selected everything from the Connection String and replaced what I originally had with it.

So the connection string looks like this now:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
          connectionString="Data Source=WODAN;Initial Catalog=IRIS;Integrated Security=True"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Here are the instructions for the attachment process (as supplied by Ladislav Mrnka)
msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx

Thanks to everyone for their input and special thanks for Ladislav for helping me through out.

Comment: Which version(s) of SQL Server (Express / otherwise) do you have installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that your .mdf file was created by newer version of SQL Server. 661 should be SQL Server 2008 R2 and you are probably using only SQL Server 2008 (that is the version you can install as part of Visual Studio 2010 installation).

Comment: Does visual studio 2010 use SQL server 2008 by default?

Comment: It uses the one defined by connection string. If you have installed both they must have different instance name which is part of connection string in `Data Source`

Comment: I have added the connection string to my post, how/what should I edit it?

Comment: What SQL version is behind `.\SQLExpress`? Because of your error it should be SQL Express 2008. What is the name of your installed SQL Express 2008 R2 instance?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a total newbie, how do I tell the instance? (Sorry)

Comment: Go to SQL server configuration manager - it should show you which instances are installed. You will find it in start menu > all programs > SQL Server XXXX > Configuration tools. Each SQL Server service represents single instance. It should be also visible by browsing running services in task manager.

Comment: I have two SQL Server: SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) and SQL server (MSSQLSERVER). Also SQL Server Agent for both versions. I can't tell which is which though.

Comment: `MSSQLSERVER` is default instance for full SQL server. Try to use `Data Source=.` in your connection string.

Comment: I don't really get what you are saying since I have "data source" in the connection string. I tried put them  in capital letters, since that was the only difference I saw.

Comment: At the moment you have `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;` try to replace it with `Data Source=.;` but I'm little bit afraid that it will not work. In such case you must go to SQL Server Management Studio and attach database to full SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx and remove `AttachDbFilename` from your connection string.

Comment: Okay, after some fiddling around (and through your generous help) I think I got it. So basically I used the attach database option, created a connection through visual studio 2010 and then (after being told) checked out the properties tab for the connection. And there it was, the whole bloody string. So this is the string I have now: connectionString="Data Source=WODAN;Initial Catalog=IRIS;Integrated Security=True" . What do you think? (And sorry for wasting your time)

Comment: It looks correct but I don't see your system so I can't validate it. You can check it by visual studio. Open server explorer and add data connection. After adding correct connection you should be able to browse the db in VS.

Comment: Okay it seems that I can (I tried to register and to login and that works), thanks a LOT (can't stress this) for the help. I'm going to add how I did this to the original post and hope that it might help some people in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Version 655 is SQL 2008. 661 is 2008 R2.  The box doesn't know how to handle the newer version.

Answer (score 1):

In the Add Connection dialog, click on the Advanced.. button.  Find the Data Source property and make sure the drop down matches the instance you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Jumping in Late. Here is what I found.

One might have both 2008 and 2008 R2 Installed on their system. But if you see the error saying it cannot open 661 version, then update your SQL Server **Express** to 2008 R2. It will fix the issue.

MDF files can be opened directly in your visual studio as long as your are using express edition of SQL server.